# Server responding with 500 error when serving SVG/PHP

Tags: php, svg

I'm trying to generate an SVG file using PHP code. I have tried implementing Technique #1 on this page:

http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/37004

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php header("Content-type: image/svg+xml"); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/ REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="310" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g style="stroke:black;fill:lightgreen" transform="translate(30,30)">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="30" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <circle cx="170" cy="25" r="20" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <line x1="265" y1="10" x2="200" y2="70" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <text x="80" y="90" style="font:size: 8"> Basic shapes</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

However, when I do this my server responds with http error 500. See:

http://isometricland.net/keyboard/test-svg.php

How can I fix this? Thanks.

[edit]

I get this error in my log:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in /home/isometr1/public_html/keyboard/test-svg.php on line 2
```

Comment: any functions missed? on my server works fine.

Comment: i think your php means <?xml is like short <? tag for <?php :-/

Comment: Did you check your error log?

Comment: If you wasn't generating this SVG files, wouldn't this files be served right from your HTTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try so:

```
<?php header("Content-type: image/svg+xml"); ?>
<?php print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/ REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="310" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g style="stroke:black;fill:lightgreen" transform="translate(30,30)">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="30" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <circle cx="170" cy="25" r="20" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <line x1="265" y1="10" x2="200" y2="70" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <text x="80" y="90" style="font:size: 8"> Basic shapes</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works. I am shocked this isn't mentioned elsewhere on the Web.

Comment: Why would it be mentioned? `<?` is the short syntax for `<?php` if it's enabled, so you're writing "version" in PHP code, which is a syntax error.